# Configure Azure's SQL Server database with ejabberd server?

Tags: sql-server, windows, xmpp, azure-sql-database, ejabberd

I want to implement a chat application, for that I'm using ejabberd for my project. I have installed ejabberd server successfully in my **Windows server** with default mnesia database. Now i want to use (Azure) SQL Server instead mnesia database. For that i have followed the [this link](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#database-and-ldap-configuration). But things that not getting clear to me.

I've added the following code inside ejabberd.yml.

```
host_config:
  "localhost":
    sql_type: mssql
    sql_server: "localhost_azure_server_name"
    sql_database: "db_name"
    sql_username: "db_username"
    sql_password: "db_password"
    auth_method: [sql]
```

I have restarted the server after the above setup. Once i try the following command

```
ejabberdctl register "test" "testserver" "test123"
```

I'm getting the following error

```
User test@testserver already registerd at node ejabberd@localhost
```

Thanks in advance, Can anyone guide to setup (Azure) MSSQL Server with ejabberd.

Comment: You are configuring for host "testserver" but are trying to register for host "localhost". There is at least one thing wrong in your config.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Mickael i have updated the config,  now it connected successfully. When i execute command to create user, it shows already created. But the user is not created in MSSQL server.

Comment: Probably your config is still wrong, possibly badly intended and it is not using the proper db and simply Mnesia internal database.